# Cannot not get the right value of custom attribute in custom transition

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-transition

I'm trying to make custom image view that have rounded corners and a custom transition to change a border radius smoothly.

In CircleTransition, I try to get imageCornerRadius but it's always return 0 which ruined the transaction. But in activity, when I get imageCornerRadius, it returns the value in xml file. So how i can get the imageCornerRadius to perform the transition.

This is declare of my custom view

**RoundedImageView**

custom attribute

```
    <declare-styleable name="RoundedImageView">
        <attr name="imageCornerRadius" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

```
class RoundedImageView : AppCompatImageView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        Log.d("debug", "first constructor")
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrSet) {
        Log.d("debug", "second constructor")

        init(attrSet)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrSet,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        Log.d("debug", "third constructor")
        init(attrSet)
    }

    private fun init(attrSet: AttributeSet){
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrSet,
            R.styleable.RoundedImageView,
            0,
            0
        ).apply {
            try {
                imageCornerRadius = getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.RoundedImageView_imageCornerRadius,
                    0
                ).toFloat()
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }
    // Custom attr
    var imageCornerRadius: Float = 0F

    //Attr for drawing
    private lateinit var bitmapRect: RectF
    val rect = RectF(drawable.bounds)
    val holePath = Path()

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        Log.d("size changed", "w = $w h = $h")
        bitmapRect = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        val drawableWidth = this.width
        val drawableHeight = this.height
        /* Clip */
        holePath.apply {
            reset()
            addRoundRect(
                0F,
                0F,
                rect.right + drawableWidth,
                rect.bottom + drawableHeight,
                imageCornerRadius,
                imageCornerRadius,
                Path.Direction.CW
            )
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            canvas?.clipPath(holePath)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            canvas?.clipPath(holePath, Region.Op.REPLACE)
        }

        // Draw image
        super.onDraw(canvas)

    }
}
```

My custom transition change Size, Coordinate, imageCornerRadius
**CircleTransition.kt**

```
class CircleTransition() : Transition() {
    private val TAG = CircleTransition::class.java.simpleName
    private val BOUNDS = TAG + ":viewBounds"
    private val CORNER_RADIUS = TAG + ":imageCornerRadius"
    private val PROPS = arrayOf(BOUNDS, CORNER_RADIUS)

    init {
        Log.d("debug", "Circle Transition called")
    }

    override fun captureStartValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues?) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }

    override fun captureEndValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues?) {
        captureValues(transitionValues)
    }


    fun captureValues(transitionValues: TransitionValues?) {
        val view = transitionValues?.view

        //get View Bound
        val bound = RectF()
        bound.left = view?.left?.toFloat() ?: return
        bound.top = view.top.toFloat()
        bound.right = view.right.toFloat()
        bound.bottom = view.bottom.toFloat()
        transitionValues.values.put(BOUNDS, bound)

        //get view Corner radius
        if(view is RoundedImageView){
            val cornerRadius = view.imageCornerRadius
            transitionValues.values.put(CORNER_RADIUS, cornerRadius)
        }
    }

    override fun getTransitionProperties(): Array<String> {
        return PROPS
    }


    override fun createAnimator(
        sceneRoot: ViewGroup?,
        startValues: TransitionValues?,
        endValues: TransitionValues?
    ): Animator? {
        if (startValues == null || endValues == null) {
            return null
        }

        val view = endValues.view as RoundedImageView
        //startScene
        val sBound = startValues.values[BOUNDS] as RectF? ?: return null
        
        //How I get imageCornerRadius
        val sCornerRadius = startValues.values[CORNER_RADIUS] as Float? ?: return null 
        val sWidth = sBound.right - sBound.left
        val sHeight = sBound.top - sBound.bottom

        //endScene
        val eBound = endValues.values[BOUNDS] as RectF? ?: return null

        //How I get imageCornerRadius
        val eCornerRadius = endValues.values[CORNER_RADIUS] as Float? ?: return null
        val eWidth = eBound.right - eBound.left
        val eHeight = eBound.top - eBound.bottom

        if (sBound == eBound && sCornerRadius == eCornerRadius) {
            return null
        }

        val widthAnimator: ValueAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofInt(sWidth.toInt(), eWidth.toInt()).apply {
                addUpdateListener {
                    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
                    layoutParams.width = it.animatedValue as Int
                    view.layoutParams = layoutParams
                }
            }

        val heightAnimator: ValueAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofInt(sHeight.toInt() * -1, eHeight.toInt() * -1).apply {
                interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
                addUpdateListener {
                    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
                    layoutParams.height = it.animatedValue as Int
                    view.layoutParams = layoutParams
                }
            }

        val cornerRadiusAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(96F, 0F).apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                view.imageCornerRadius = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        // set endView have the same size, coorinate like startScene
        view.x = sBound.left
        view.y = sBound.top

//        view.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(sBound.width().toInt(), sBound.height().toInt())
        // move view
        val startX = sBound.left
        val startY = sBound.top

        val moveXTo = eBound.left
        val moveYTo = eBound.top

        val moveXAnimator: Animator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", startX, moveXTo.toFloat())
        val moveYAnimator: Animator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", startY, moveYTo.toFloat()).apply {
                addUpdateListener {
                    view.invalidate()
                }
            }


        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playTogether(
            widthAnimator,
            heightAnimator,
            cornerRadiusAnimator,
            moveXAnimator,
            moveYAnimator
        )
        return animatorSet
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with kotlin but I would say you use the wrong context and maybe the wrong theme to obtain your attribute. Try by passing the context from the constructor to your init function as argument.

Comment: @TeddySmith I have check the init() it return the right value. I add RoundedImageView in the xml file so I don't think I use the wrong context.